# Should be simple inductive proof

Tags: statistics, summation

Establish the following recursion relations for means and variances. Let $\overline{X}_n$ and $S_n^2$ be the mean and variance, respectively, of $X_1,\dots,X_n$. Then suppose another observation, $X_{n+1}$. becomes available. Show that

> 1. $\overline{X}_{n+1}=\dfrac{X_{n+1} + n\overline{X}_n}{n+1}\\$
> 2. $nS_{n+1}^2 = (n-1)S_{n}^2 + \dfrac{n}{n+1}(X_{n+1} - \overline{X}_{n})^2 $

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify exactly what you are trying to prove? (Maybe you can copy the original problem here.)

Comment: Sorry. I guess I've just been staring at it so long that I'm not very coherent. Prove the second statement by expanding the first for k+1.

Comment: just write/copy the original question, it makes it hard to parse for everyone.

Comment: @ColtonWilliams I'm sorry, but could you please write the original problem, word-for-word? There are subtle details in the problem that you are not telling us, and perhaps that might be the very reason why you weren't able to solve the problem in the first place.

Comment: Ok. Yes....I'll write it now

Comment: @ColtonWilliams Thank you. Now I understand the problem. I'll post an answer shortly.

Comment: @ColtonWilliams Here, the variance is the sample variance, correct?

Comment: There is still a mistake in your edit. $X_n +1$ in 1) must be changed into $X_{n+1}$

Comment: @Braindead Yes it is. Thank you

Comment: @drhab Fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In this answer 1) is taken for granted and is used to prove 2). Start by rewriting 1) as: $$\bar{X}_{n+1}-\bar{X}_{n}=\dfrac{X_{n+1}-\bar{X}_{n}}{n+1}$$ 
Now we will prove 2):
$$nS_{n+1}^{2}=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\left(X_{i}-\bar{X}_{n+1}\right)^{2}=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\left(\left(X_{i}-\bar{X}_{n}\right)-\left(\bar{X}_{n+1}-\bar{X}_{n}\right)\right)^{2}=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\left(X_{i}-\bar{X}_{n}\right)^{2}-2\left(\bar{X}_{n+1}-\bar{X}_{n}\right)\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\left(X_{i}-\bar{X}_{n}\right)+\left(n+1\right)\left(\bar{X}_{n+1}-\bar{X}_{n}\right)^{2}$$

Here:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\left(X_{i}-\bar{X}_{n}\right)^{2}=\left(n-1\right)S_{n}^{2}+\left(X_{n+1}-\bar{X}_{n}\right)^{2}$$

and:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\left(X_{i}-\bar{X}_{n}\right)=\left(X_{n+1}-\bar{X}_{n}\right)$$

Now substitute 1) i.e. $\bar{X}_{n+1}-\bar{X}_{n}=\dfrac{X_{n+1}-\bar{X}_{n}}{n+1}$
to find that:

$$\left(\bar{X}_{n+1}-\bar{X}_{n}\right)\left(X_{n+1}-\bar{X}_{n}\right)=\frac{1}{n+1}\left(X_{n+1}-\bar{X}_{n}\right)^{2}$$

and:

$$\left(\bar{X}_{n+1}-\bar{X}_{n}\right)^{2}=\frac{1}{\left(n+1\right)^{2}}\left(X_{n+1}-\bar{X}_{n}\right)^{2}$$

leading to:

$$nS_{n+1}^{2}=\left(n-1\right)S_{n}^{2}+\frac{n}{n+1}\left(X_{n+1}-\bar{X}_{n}\right)^{2}$$

Comment: You beat me to it! :P

Comment: @Braindead I reckon I was ready just in time :-)